# Alternative to Input Director

Tags: windows, macos, software-rec

Is there an alternative to `Input Director` for Mac OS X, which will seamlessly move mouse from Windows PC to Mac OS? `Synergy` does it only through shortcut key and haven't been updated for ages.

Comment: Go here http://alternativeto.net/software/input-director/ , other than this i cant find anything which can help you

Comment: @subanki I think your comment would work well as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Share Mouse](http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com). It lets you share your mouse and keyboard with multiple networked computers.

Comment: Share Mouse licensing is $50 if you have more than one monitor on either computer. As I (like many) have a dual-monitor main PC setup, it would cost $50. I'll pass.

Answer (score 3):

Synergy a solution. I'd like to correct a few points that you've made:

- Synergy allows you to move your mouse seamlessly; no shortcut key is required.
- The project is in active development and has had a recent release.

Synergy is feature-restricted in the "free open source" version and you must donate to the developers in order to get all features and have bugs fixed with priority.

Synergy works on Linux too.

Disclaimer: I am affiliated with Synergy.

Comment: Looks good, but it's good netiquette to acknowledge in your response that you are affiliated with the product.

Answer (score 0):

Share Mouse works and is free-of-charge for non-power users. It will tell you if you're a professional user and have to pay $20 to continue using it.

Comment: Share Mouse licensing is $50 if you have more than one monitor on either computer. As I (like many) have a dual-monitor main PC setup, it would cost $50. I'll pass.